# Удаление елемента массива, который является полем класса

Tags: c++, ооп

Нужно чтобы метод pop(); удалял элемент массива ptr по индексу, я пытался это сделать классическим способом, но код крушиться.
Есть ли легальный способ удалить элемент из массива по индексу ?

void pop(int z) {

```
    for (int i = z; i < x; i++) {
        ptr[i] = ptr[i + 1];
    }
    x = x - 1;
}
```

выше сам метод pop();
а вот и сам код

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
class PC {
public:
    int i_one = 0;
    int i_t=0;
    int i_h=0;
    int i_p=0;
    int i_l=0;
    int i_m=0;
    int i_n=0;
    int i_b=0;

    int x =16;

    string* ptr = new string[x];

    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {


                cout << ptr[i] <<" and NOMER: "<<i<< endl;

        }
    }

    void other_add() {
        //int i_one = 0;

        cout << "enter marka  PC:" << "; " << endl;
        cin >> mark_pk;
        ptr[0 + i_one] = mark_pk;
        i_one += 8;
    }
    void other_add_1() {
      //  int i_t = 0;
        cout << "enter type processor:"  << "; " << endl;
        cin >> type_proc;
        ptr[1 + i_t] = type_proc;
        i_t += 8;
    }
    void other_add_2() {
      //  int i_h = 0;
        cout << " tact chastota procesora:" << endl;
        cin >> takt;
        ptr[2 + i_h] = takt;
        i_h += 8;
    }
    void other_add_3() {
      //  int i_p = 0;
        cout <<" obem memory:" << endl;
        cin >> ob_memor;
        ptr[3 + i_p] = ob_memor;
        i_p += 8;
    }
    void other_add_4() {
       // int i_l = 0;
        cout << " obem gorstkoho disc: "  << endl;
        cin >> ob_gr_disk;
        ptr[4 + i_l] = ob_gr_disk;
        i_l += 8;
    }
    void other_add_5() {
       // int i_m = 0;
        cout << "obem video card:" <<  endl;
        cin >> ob_memor_video;
        ptr[5 + i_m] = ob_memor_video;
        i_m += 8;
    }
    void other_add_6() {
      //  int i_n = 0;
        cout << "value PC:" << value_pc << endl;
        cin >> value_pc;
        ptr[6 + i_n] = value_pc;
        i_n += 8;
    }
    void other_add_7() {
       // int i_b = 0;
        cout << " kilk in nayavnosti"  << endl;
        cin >> kilkist;
        ptr[7 + i_b] = kilkist;
        i_b += 8;

    }
    void add() {


        other_add();
        other_add_1();
        other_add_2();
        other_add_3();
        other_add_4();
        other_add_5();
        other_add_6();
        other_add_7();



    }

    string nazva_pc;
    string mark_pk;
    string type_proc;
    string  takt;
    string ob_memor;
    string ob_gr_disk;
    string ob_memor_video;
    string value_pc;
    string kilkist;
    void pop(int z) {

        for (int i = z; i < x; i++) {
            ptr[i] = ptr[i + 1];
        }
        x = x - 1;


    }
};
int main()
{

    PC *s=new PC;

    s->add();
    s->add();

    cout << "fffffffffffffffffffffffffff" << endl;

    s->pop(5);
    s->print();
    }
```

Comment: `for (int i = z; i < x; i++) {
        ptr[i] = ptr[i + 1];` - что будет при `i==x-1`? Обращение к `ptr[x]` за пределами массива. UB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Попробуй данный алгоритм(Удаление элемента по индексу из динамического массива):**

**1)** Создай массив-копию,который будет содержать **N-1** элементов(N-количество элементов изначального массива).

**2)** Сохрани в этот массив(копию) все элементы,кроме того,который нужно удалить.

**3)** Очисти память,выделенную под изначальный массив(в котором **N** элементов).

**4)** Теперь выдели под этот массив(который только что почистил) память под **N-1** элементов.

**5)** Cкопируй все значения из массива-копии в исходный массив,с которым работал в пункте 4.

**6)** Очисти память под массив-копию.

**ГОТОВО!**

**P.S:** Написал алгоритм так,чтобы подумал,если нужен код,скажи,напишу:)

Comment: Простите уж, но решение из серии "зачем просто и быстро, если можно сложно и медленно"... Особенно радуют пункты 3-5. Поясните, зачем они? если даже копировать - ну так удалите исходный массив и присвойте ему указатель на временный (если, понятно, исходный массив выделен динамически. А если статически, что вы будете делать, кстати?)

Comment: @Harry Я,как и человек,который задал вопрос-начинающие,стало быть ему  понятнее такое объяснение.Я вас прекрасно помню,вы мне много раз отвечали на мои вопросы,без сомнения,вы намного опытнее.Я написал свой ответ,c целью хоть как-нибудь помочь человеку.Насчет эффективности я с вами полностью согласен.

Comment: Ну просто зацепило это решение - выделить новый массив, скопировать, но потом вместо чтоб им заменить старый - нет, удалить старый, выделить новый, скопировать все заново назад. Эти лишние копирования не делают ответ понятнее, но делают его неэффективным. Это даже не преждевременная оптимизация - это уже какая-то преднамеренная пессимизация...

Comment: @Harry а можете пожалуйста пример привести,не совсем понимаю как замену эту сделать.Заранее спасибо!

Comment: **Если массив динамический**, типа `int * ptr` - то вы собирались делать что? `int*tmp = new int[..];`, копирование, `delete[]ptr;`, `ptr = new  int[...];`, копирование, `delete tmp;`. А достаточно после `delete[]ptr;` просто `ptr=tmp;` и все.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо большое!